# How can I delete all Documents with Ektorp in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, ektorp

I'm trying to delete all the saved documents in CouchDB with Ektorp. A document can I delete so:

```
public void deleteDoc(Object o) {
    db.delete(o);
}
```

But for all Docs? can any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete all docs, why don't you just drop the database?

Or you can use the bulk operations in Ektorp:

```
List<Object> bulkDocs = ...
Sofa toBeDeleted = ...

bulkDocs.add(BulkDeleteDocument.of(toBeDeleted));

db.executeBulk(bulkDocs);
```

read more here:
http://ektorp.org/reference_documentation.html#d100e642